# How can I query 2 tables and return results if 2nd table matches condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I developed a game that has many tournaments that run.  All the running tournaments are stored in the **running_tournaments** table.  When a player enters a tournament, their score for that tournament is saved in the **scores** table.

I'd like to write a script that periodically checks the database to see if there are any tournaments that have ended (their end_date is in the past) AND all the scores for that tournament have been "verified".  A score is considered verified when the verified value for that score is "1".

How can I query these tables to return all the tournament id's of the tournaments where all the scores for that tournament have been verified (verified = 1)?

As an example, given the data below, if today's date is January 3rd, the query should only return tournament id # 1.  Tournament id 1 has two scores that have been verified and it's date is on or before today.  All other tournaments are either in the future or have 1 or more scores that are not verified.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . I think `join` and `group by` does what you want:

```
select s.tourn_id
from scores s join
     running_tournaments rt
     on s.tourn_id = rt.id
where end_date <= curdate()
group by s.tourn_id
having min(s.verified) = 1;
```